# Prove $\sqrt{-7} \not\in \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{2+3\sqrt{-7}}{4}\right]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

I have the following problem.

> Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ and define:
>   $$x = \sqrt{-7}\qquad z = \frac{2+3x}{4}$$
>   Show that $\mathbb{Z}[x] \not\subset \mathbb{Z}[z]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[z] \not\subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

First of all, I describe the ring extensions:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}[x] 
&= \left\{a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +a_3 x^3 + \ldots  \ | \ a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\\
&= \left\{a + b x \ | \ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
\end{align}
Where we use $x^2 + 7 = 0$ ($x$ is an algebraic integer). On the other hand
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}[z] 
&= \left\{a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 +a_3 z^3 + \ldots  \ | \ a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
\end{align}
admits no further simplification (we have $16z^2 - 16z + 67 = 0 \Rightarrow z$ is not an algebraic integer).

---

I think it is easy to show $z \not\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. To see this, assume you can find $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $z = a+bx$. Now consider this identity in $\mathbb{Q}(x) = \mathbb{Q}[x]$, where $\{1,x\}$ is a basis. Since 
$$z=\frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{4}\!x= a +bx $$
it must be $a=\frac{2}{4}$, $b=\frac{3}{4}$, so $a, b$ are not in $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $z\not\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

---

- Is this correct?
- Any idea for the other part?

Comment: Your approach for the first part is spot on, though you should have $\Bbb Z$ instead of $\Bbb N$ in both versions of your definition of $\Bbb Z[x].$

Also, for the second part, there is a key thing to notice: $$\Bbb Z[z]:=\left\{a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots\mid\text{each }a_i\in\Bbb Z,\text{ and all but finitely-many }a_i=0\right\}.$$

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thanks, That was a typo, now $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. For the second part, I don't see why assuming $x = P(z)$ (for some $P\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with finite degree, of course) should lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Neither do I (yet), but I wanted to make sure you weren't using formal power series.

Comment: It may be possible to try $x\not\in \mathbb{Z}\left[z,\, \frac{1}{2}\right]$. Since $z^2 - z + 3/16 = z^2 - z + 3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 = 0$, we can write $$\mathbb{Z}\left[z, \frac{1}{2}\right] = \left\{a_0 + a_1 z \ | \ a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]\right\}$$ and use the same approach.

Comment: That seems very promising! If it ends up working out, you should write it up as an answer (which is explicitly allowed, and even encouraged). Let me know, and I'll even upvote it, and (once a few days have gone by) you can accept it, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for $z\not\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is correct.  For $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}[z]$, a nice trick is to consider what's going on mod 3.  Note that $\mathbb{Z}[z]\cong\mathbb{Z}[t]/(16t^2-16t+67)$ and $2$ is a root of $16t^2-16t+67$ mod $3$, so there is a homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[z]\to \mathbb{F}_3$ such that $\varphi(z)=2$.  (Intuitively, this is just a rigorous version of saying that mod $3$, $z=\frac{2+3\sqrt{-7}}{4}=\frac{2}{4}=2$.)

Now suppose $x$ were in $\mathbb{Z}[z]$.  Then $\varphi(x)$ would satisfy $\varphi(x)^2=-7=2$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$.  Since $2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}_3$, this is a contradiction.